# How to manually list out the classes present in a package via command prompt?

Tags: java

What is the Windows Command Prompt command for listing all the classes present in a package.

I knew that to list out methods, for eg javap java.lang.String

is there anything for my question?

Additional Details: My question is for pre-defined Classes, please do provide for user defined classes packed in jar too...!

Comment: Classes located where? In the JDK rt, in another jar, war, ear,  etc, etc, etc?

Comment: @ShashankKadne My question is for pre-defined Classes, please do provide for user defined classes for jar too...!

Comment: @ShashankKadne - for example I am doing a program suddenly i have forgotten what class to be Added while importing from a pre-defined package. So thats why i am asking. I hope that you have understood the situation.

Answer (score 2):

If your classes are not packed into jar file use either `ls` or `dir` command (dependent on your OS). If the classes are into jar use command `jar -vft yourjar.jar` and and either `grep` or `find`, e.g.

`jar -vft myjar.jar | grep 'com/mycompany/myproject'` for Unix
`jar -vft myjar.jar | find "com/mycompany/myproject"` for Windows

Comment: for example I am doing a program suddenly i have forgotten what class to be Added while importing from a pre-defined package. So thats why i am asking. I hope that you have understood the situation

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
jar -tvf filename.jar
```

Where filename.jar is your file

Comment: for example If I am doing a program suddenly i have forgotten what class to be Added while importing from a pre-defined package. So thats why i am asking. I hope that you have understood the situation